# How to send data to different tabs using a userform?

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have created a spreadsheet which is used to log a lot of data via a userform. In this userform the initial data will always go to a masterdata tab within the spreadsheet. My issue however, is that I have another 3 worksheets, ws2, ws3 and ws4.

Now based on 4 fields within the userform there are 16 possible different outcomes which would decide if this data is also required to be included into ws2 & ws3, or ws3, or ws 2, or ws2 and ws 4, or just ws 4 etc....

The rules are as follows:

[image]

Can someone please let me know a way of getting this information across the necessary sheets. Below is my code for the userform

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Nextnum As Long
Dim Xnum As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

Nextnum = Sheets("MasterData").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
Xnum = Sheets("X").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
ANum = Sheets("A").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
CNum = Sheets("C").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Value + 1

'find first empty row in database
mrow = ws1.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy the data to the database
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 1).Value = Nextnum
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 3).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 4).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "WW"))
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 5).Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 6).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "YYYY"))
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 7).Value = 1
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 8).Value = TxtWeight.Value * (1300 / 1000)
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBrd.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("G:H"), 2, False)
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 10).Value = Application.UserName
                If ComboBrd.Value = "Mn" Then ws1.Cells(mrow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("L:N"), 2, False) Else
                If ComboBrd.Value = "Pr" Then ws1.Cells(mrow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False) Else
                    If ComboBrd.Value = "Vot" Then ws1.Cells(mrow, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboCom.Value, Sheets("Lookup Vals").Range("P:R"), 2, False)
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 12).Value = TxtRecDate.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 13).Value = ComboPD.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 14).Value = ComboNP.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 15).Value = ComboBrd.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 16).Value = ComboCom.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 17).Value = TxtAdditional.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 18).Value = TxtDOD.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 19).Value = TxtBn.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 20).Value = TxtFS.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 21).Value = ComboPrdG.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 22).Value = ComboIss.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 23).Value = TxtUni.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 24).Value = TxtWet.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 25).Value = TxtInc.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 26).Value = TxtDet.Value
    ws1.Cells(mrow, 27).Value = TxtShr.Value
```

If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try addine `Me.` before all your userform objects (if this code in located inside the Userform). Like `ws1.Cells(mrow, 8).Value = TxtWeight.Value * (1300 / 1000)` should be `ws1.Cells(mrow, 8).Value = Me.TxtWeight.Value * (1300 / 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

I think select case would be helpful creating an array of worksheets that should be filled out. After just loop through and add the data:

```
Dim targetWorksheets As Variant

Select Case True
Case c1 And c2 And c3 >= 50 And c4 <= 1: targetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
Case c1 And c2 And c3 >= 50 And c4 > 1: targetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
'etc ....
Case Else: targetWorksheets = Array(ws1)
End Select 

For Each ws In targetWorksheets
    mrow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(mrow, 1).Value = Nextnum
    ws.Cells(mrow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(mrow, 3).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
    ws.Cells(mrow, 4).Value = CInt(Format(Date, "WW"))
    'etc
Next ws
```

Gr